# Self storage of notes with extended formatting

Tags: icloud, notes.app

The notes app on OSX and iOS offers to sync notes with e-mail accounts. I noticed that for notes synced with an icloud account, the app offers extended formatting possibilies (I use checkboxes and hand drawing, but there might be more). When synced with another e-mail account (I tested hotmail, gmail, bluewin.ch and my work e-mail), those features are not available.

Hence my question: is there any provider that can offer this extended formatting? What would they need to provide that the one I tested don't?

Context: I am looking for a replacement of our current e-mail provider at work. icloud is not an option since we want to have our e-mails stored in Switzerland, where we are based. I was wondering if we could find a provider offering those possibilities.

PS: while researching I stumbled upon [this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40792/mycloud-is-self-hosting-icloud-possible?rq=1). My question, although similar, is limited to notes.app, not the entire panel of icloud services.